# Stop IE11 removing text from input type number

Tags: html, internet-explorer-11

In Internet Explorer 11, if you have the following:

```
<input type="number" min="1" max="12" pattern="[0-9]*" >
```

When a user tries to input letters rather than numbers, the browser just clears the input. This behaviour is undesirable as I want our validation to handle this, rather than the browser automatically doing it for me.

Does anybody know how to change this behaviour?

[image: Example Image]

I'm using the number input type for validation and also to get the correct keyboard in iOS.

[JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hcharge/e1132tg5/1/).

Comment: By reprogramming the desired numberfield behaviour in javascript, and using input type text...

Comment: your input say `input type="number"`, but then you are trying to add letters to the field?

Comment: Might be nicer to just not allow any input of anything other than 0123456789 at all. The user types a letter and the input goes red with a little message that says something like "input must be a number". Have that behaviour cross browser.

Comment: Yes @misterManSam that is what we are doing, the issue though is that IE11 removes the text before it has a chance to validate, so we don't get the validation message at all. Ohh do you mean literally as soon as the user types in the input? That is an option yes, I will explore that!

Comment: The `pattern` attribute is invalid for `type=number` and is ignored by IE 11.

Comment: @hcharge - Yes, prevent the input of non number characters in the first place. That would reduce confusion if it is accompanied by a simple error indicating only numbers are accepted. Also, maybe grey placeholder numbers - 01 01 1990 - to subtly indicate the desired input. Maybe.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela that's interesting, as adding the pattern attribute gives the telephone keyboard on iOS, which is desired. I had considered just using the telephone input altogether, but it's not really semantically correct.

Answer (score 3):

Other browsers may keep this text present, however entering "aaa" into an `input` element whose `type` attribute is set to "number" will mean that your element's `value` property is empty, so your validation method would most likely regard this as a lack of content rather than a non-numerical value anyway.

```
<input type="number" value="aaa" />
```

```js
console.log(document.querySelector('input').value);
> ""
```

I've altered your JSFiddle demo to reflect this: http://jsfiddle.net/e1132tg5/3/.

If you need to accept non-numerical data in your `input` element then the solution is quite simply to change your element's `type` to "text" instead of "number" and rely solely on your own JavaScript validation methods for handling the validation (as it appears you want anyway).

```
<input type="text" >
```

You can always also use your JavaScript to determine whether the user is viewing your site on a mobile device and change the `type` attribute dynamically.

An alternate solution would be to inform the user that the field must be numerical if the element is blurred with no text present (after IE's automatic removal), but this would be better discussed on [SE's UserExperience site](http://ux.stackexchange.com).

Comment: Hi James, thanks very much for your answer. Yes I guess the issue is users not knowing that the input is number only. We have validation on these fields so that in other browsers losing focus from the field would provide an error with letters, and as you say IE doesn't because it never truly has that value. The issue has only come about through QA testing, and I doubt a user would ever run into this problem. But it's interesting to see IE11's behaviour.

Answer (score -3):

Just use regex instead:

```
<input type="text" name="amount" id="amount"
    data-val="true"
    data-val-required="Amount field cannot be empty."
    data-val-regex-pattern="^[0-9+.\s]*$"
    data-val-regex="Amount field must be numeric"
    placeholder="Amount">
<span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="amount" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
```

Comment: this is not standard validation - I assume you are using some sort of third party JS library which looks at these data-* attributes.

Comment: agree with @psynnott. add the name of the 3rd party lib you're using